# <a4j:commandLink> action not fired inside <form>

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am working on an enhancement project. There is a parent `<form>` element. I have an XHTML file included inside this parent form. The included XHTML file has an `<a4j:commandLink>`. This action is not getting called.
Now, this will work if i wrap the `<a4j:commandLink>` inside an `<h:form>`. This way, the parent form's action is called as well as the `<a4j:commandLink>`'s action. But nesting forms is not encouraged.
I can't use the parent form's action because it goes to a servlet and my action is in a 
request scoped bean. I cant access the bean in the servlet.
Any help on how to make the action call without the `<h:form>` is highly appreciated.
Here is how it looks like:

```
    <form id="parentFormId" name="parentFormId" action="aservletaction">
      <a4j:outputPanel id="includedRegion">

        <ui:include src="setupView.xhtml"></ui:include>
     </a4j:outputPanel>
   </form>
```

Contents of setupView.xhtml:

```
<ui:composition>
   <a4j:outputPanel>
        <h:form>
        <a4j:commandLink action="#{myBean.actionMethod}"
          render="adatatableid" limitRender="true"/>
        </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RichFaces components have to be inside a form otherwise they won't work (at least the executable ones).

Now, `<a4j:commandLink>` (and commandButton) executing the whole form is the default behaviour, to change it use the `execute` [attribute](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Common_Ajax_attributes.html#sect-Component_Reference-Data_processing-execute):

```
<a4j:commandLink execute="@this" … >
```

This will limit the execution only to the link.

Comment: Thank you Makhiel. That worked. I don't have to use <h:form> around the commandLink. This way it calls the bean's action. The only drawback is, it still submits the parent form.

Comment: Can't the parent be `<h:form>` though? The point of the commandLink is that it takes over the functionality of the form (i.e. you define action for the link, not for the form). What is the usual for that parent form to be submitted?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can't keep the parent form as '<h:form>'. The page is quite big with lots of servlet calls, and every other submit needs to go through the form's action. I just examined the POST call details in firebug. The whole form contents are going part of the POST call. But I can see that javax.faces.partial.ajax=true.

Comment: Okay but said "every other submit" is executed by some component, can't that component call the bean directly? If you're using anything else besides RichFaces then you probably know better than me, but otherwise such design seems strange to me. :) I've never used forms for anything but necessary decoration.

Comment: No. It can't. I checked the bean instance using spring's getBean(...) method. It returned null. I need the current instance of the bean to call the action method.

Answer (score 1):

It ought not work. **Do not nest forms**, as its not legal in HTML in general and in HTML code *rendered by JSF* in particular. So, you've got a following construct in your code:

```
<form>
    ...
    <h:form>
        ...
    </h:form>
    ...
</form>
```

Get rid if it and it'll work as expected, i.e. by creating a plain form-to-form structure.

Comment: i think you have not read the description. I know its not legal to nest forms, however this way it calls the action method in the bean. If i remove the form wrapping commandLink, the action never gets called, because the parent form's action get called and somehow the commandLink's action disappears. What I am looking for is a way to still call the action of commandLink without the nested forms.

Comment: You need to properly cluster your data. Two side-to-side forms is a viable option, as I stated in my answer. Another thing to understand is that **two forms are posting to different urls**.

Comment: Let me specify my question in a different way: Is there a way I can have an action called from a4j:commandLink's action attribute, without depending on parent form?